# Efficient way to convert CSV to Sparse Matrix in R

Tags: r, csv, sparse-matrix

I have a very large csv file (about 91 million rows so a for loop takes too long in R) of similarities between keywords that when I read into a data.frame looks like:

```
> df   
kwd1 kwd2 similarity  
a  b  1  
b  a  1  
c  a  2  
a  c  2
```

It is a sparse list and I would like to convert it into a sparse matrix:

```
> myMatrix 
  a b c  
a . 1 2
b 1 . .
c 2 . .
```

I tried using sparseMatrix(), but converting the keyword names to integer indexes takes too much time.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why do you have a *possible duplicate* header on your question?

Comment: That was from a different post, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`acast` from the `reshape2` package will do this nicely.  There are base R solutions but I find the syntax much more difficult.

```
library(reshape2)
df <- structure(list(kwd1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c"), class = "factor"), kwd2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), similarity = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("kwd1", "kwd2", "similarity"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

acast(df, kwd1 ~ kwd2, value.var='similarity', fill=0)

  a b c
a 0 1 2
b 1 0 0
c 2 0 0
>
```

---

using `sparseMatrix` from the `Matrix` package:

```
library(Matrix)
df$kwd1 <- factor(df$kwd1)
df$kwd2 <- factor(df$kwd2)

foo <- sparseMatrix(as.integer(df$kwd1), as.integer(df$kwd2), x=df$similarity)

> foo
3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"


foo <- sparseMatrix(as.integer(df$kwd1), as.integer(df$kwd2), x=df$similarity, dimnames=list(levels(df$kwd1), levels(df$kwd2)))

> foo 

3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
  a b c
a . 1 2
b 1 . .
c 2 . .
```

Comment: Hmm I will try this. However, will this give me a sparse matrix? Memory won't allow for a dense matrix with 0's.

Comment: Maybe if I set drop to true it will be sparse.

Comment: Ok, this is is like what I was doing with sparse matrix before. However, I was having a problem wit converting the keywords to integer indexes, but I was using apply and which to do what as.integer is doing here. Hopefully this will be faster!

Comment: Don't miss the `factor()` step! that is how I am forcing the `as.integer` to work and how the `dimnames` argument works too.  Also, if I've answered your question, please mark it as such by clicking the checkmark.  that way others know the question has been resolved.

Comment: I am now trying to convert this matrix to a dist object, but it reports an error that the 'problem is too large'. If you any insight, I have posted another question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379233/efficient-way-to-convert-csv-of-sparse-distances-to-dist-object-r

Thanks for help! If there is anyway to rate your answer besides up arrowing I would be happy to do so.